# Change default docker user after container has started

Tags: docker, dockerfile

So I have to run the processes inside the container as root. They afterwards spawn processes with a predefined non-root user. However after the main process has been started I would like all other commands to be executed as non-root user, including exec from outside the container.

If I use `USER user` inside the Dockerfile - the main process also starts as `user` and it breaks the logic. (I know best practices are not to run containers processes as root, but in some cases it's needed)

After the container is running - I can exec with the non-root `user` by explicitly specifying the user in the docker or docker-compose commands. However I want to default to non-root user without specifying it explicitly in every CLI command. Exactly how the `USER user` behaves (or `user` inside the docker-compose file). Is there a way to do that?

Also the other way around would also be fine: if I can set `USER user` but explicitly run the main process as `root` ignoring that directive?

EDIT: Also tried running `su - user` at the end of the entrypoint. While this makes the next commands in the entrypoint itself be executes as non-root it does not make the default user non-root meaning the `docker exec` will still use the root user.

End result should be like:

- Command from entrypoint should be executes as `root`.
- Everything else should be executed by non-root `user`.
- When you run `docker-compose exec container command` it should be with non-root `user` without explicitly specifying it.
- If you run `docker exec container command` it should also be non-root `user` without explicitly specifying it.

Comment: I wouldn't really worry about `docker exec` as a use case.  Anyone who can run it can also use Docker to compromise the entire host system.  IME it should be pretty unusual to need to do any sort of manual work inside a container shell, especially since that will be lost as soon as the container is deleted and recreated (for example, on the next build of your application).

Comment: @DavidMaze there are few use cases. Some application that use docker does not specify a user when using exec into the container. One example of this is the JetBrains IDEs which 'Terminal' uses the default user without option to configure it. Some of those images will be also used locally by the developers and not having to type something on each command is saving time and problems. I have quite enough reasons to want the default user to be non-root.